# Threading in Spring

Tags: multithreading, spring, hibernate, session, caching

I'm trying to do some optimization in my code and would like to spawn a thread where I do a time consuming operation. During the implementation of that optimization I was running into an issue which was driving me crazy. I simplified the issue and created a test case for that specific issue: (I'm using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner so the transaction is properly started at the beginning of the testCRUD method)

Could someone help me understand why the foundParent is null in the thread ?

```
private Semaphore sema = new Semaphore(0, false);
private long parentId;

@Test
public void testCRUD() {
    //create
    DBParent parent = null;
    {
        parent = new DBParent();
        parentDao.persist(parent);
        parentId = parent.getId();
        assertTrue(parentId > 0);

        parentDao.flush();
    }

    (new Thread(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
            {
                System.out.println("Start adding childs !");
                DBParent foundParent = parentDao.findById(parentId);
                assertTrue(foundParent != null); //ASSERTION FAILS HERE !!!!

                System.out.println("Releasing semaphore !");
                sema.release();
                System.out.println("End adding childs !");
            }
    })).start();

    try {
        System.out.println("Acquiring semaphore !");
        sema.acquire();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

=============================EDITED===================================
As per one comment suggestion, I created a threadManager bean which spawn the thread. Here is the code of the threadManager:

```
public class ThreadManager {
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void executeTask(String Name, Runnable task) {
        (new Thread(task, Name)).start();
    }
 }
```

Then in the previous test, instead of staring the thread manually, I just post it in the thread manager like this:

```
@Autowired private ParentDao parentDao;
@Autowired private ThreadManager threadManager;

private Semaphore sema = new Semaphore(0, false);
private long parentId;

@Test
public void testCRUD() {
    //create
    DBParent parent = null;
    {
        parent = new DBParent();
        parentDao.persist(parent);
        parentId = parent.getId();
        assertTrue(parentId > 0);

        parentDao.flush();
    }

    threadManager.executeTask("BG processing...",
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
            {
                System.out.println("Start adding childs !");
                DBParent foundParent = parentDao.findById(parentId);
                assertTrue(foundParent != null); //ASSERTION FAILS HERE !!!!

                System.out.println("Releasing semaphore !");
                sema.release();
                System.out.println("End adding childs !");
            }
    });

    try {
        System.out.println("Acquiring semaphore !");
        sema.acquire();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work either !!! :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transaction context is bound to the thread. So the code in the spawned thread doesn't run in the same transaction context as the code in the initial thread. So, due to transaction isolation (the I in ACID), the spawned thread doesn't see what the initial thread's transaction is inserting in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! So what is the recommended way to trigger a background thread in spring which sees the modification in the context made on the parent thread ? Is it just not possible ?

Comment: It's not possible unless the parent thread has committed the transaction before spawning the child thread.

Comment: Actually what I would need is a generic way to share transaction context between threads...

Comment: No way. JPA persistence contexts/hibernate sessions are not thread-safe anyway.

Comment: Last question then : I'm using a shared entity manager and when I try to do parentDao.getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit(); I'm getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead". Is there a way to manually commit the transaction ?

Comment: Not if it's a declarative transaction. You should simply invoke another Spring bean method annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)`. This bean method will start and commit its own transaction. Then you can span a thread that will see the updates made in this committed transaction.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but this doesn't work either :-( (I've edited the original post)

Comment: That's not what I suggested. What I suggested is to start by calling another bean method marked with REQUIRES_NEW and, when this method has returned, to spawn a child thread.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* bind Spring transaction to a new thread, to run transactions & Hibernate/JPA access in it. But this has to be a different TX and JPA/HB session from other threads.

Spring code for `OpenSessionInViewFilter`, is a reasonable an example of how to bind Hibernate session to Spring's TX management. You can strip this down to fairly minimal code.

See:

- `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter`
- `OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal()`  -- this is where it actually binds it
- `TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource()`
- `TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource()`
- `TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource()`

In one project (IIRC) I wrapped this functionality into a 'ServerThreadHb' class, to setup & save previous thread-bindings on construction -- with a `restore()` method to be called in a `finally` block, to restore previous bindings.

For your posted code sample, there isn't much point in running work on a separate thread -- since you synchronously wait for the work to be done. However I assume you were planning to remove that constraint & extend that functionality.

Comment: Not sure to fully understand. Do you have a code snippet to share ?

Comment: I think calling `bindResource()` and `unbindResource()` with a Hibernate `Session` should be pretty straightforward??? Actually, you have to wrap the session in a SessionHolder.. but that's about it. Did you look at the OpenSessionInView code?

Comment: Nop ... still the same error even with this modified code:        

                    try{
                        TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory, new SessionHolder(currentSession));
                        
                        DBParent foundParent = parentDao.findById(parentId);
        ....
                    }
                    finally {
                    TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(sessionFactory);
                    }

Comment: Yep, that _should_ be pretty much what you need to do -- my code's in a work project & not here at home though. **Analysis for you to debug & confirm:** So.. looks like your (existing) Session is correctly bound onto the new thread -- check that both calls into parentDao pick it up the same, though -- so is the problem that `findById()` is still returning null? **Really need to establish whether both threads are actually using the same session** -- and also whether instead the TX should be committed before forking, and separate session should be used for the thread.